# inject html to an existing page without being affected by css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to inject some html content to an existing page without being affected by page's css

I search and find something called shadow dom

when i try to apply the solution , error occurred

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var host = document.querySelector('#content');

        var shadowRoot = host.createShadowRoot();

    </script>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createShadowRoot' of null

Comment: It looks like `createShadowRoot()` has been deprecated and doesn't have much support in browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot

Comment: You can use `iframe`

Comment: `This feature has been removed from the Web standards` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot Although the error (`host` is `null`) indicates that `#content` wasn't found.

Comment: @gabriel , i have div with that id

Comment: Does the `div` exist at the moment of the execution? Try running the code on load or domready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element.createShadowRoot()` has been deprecated in favour of `Element.attachShadow()`.

You may use:

```
// Get content
var content = document.querySelector('#content');

// Create shadow root
var shadow = content.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

// Create text node
var text = document.createElement('span');
text.textContent = "hello";

// Append it to the shadow root
shadow.appendChild(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`<iframe>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag to acheive that.

You need to separate the new HTML into a new page, then call it in your main page:

```
<iframe src="newPage.html"></iframe>
```

In `newPage.html` you should insert all of the HTML that you don't want to be effected by your main page's CSS.

---

Example:

**main.html**

```
<p class="bold">Main page bold</p>

<iframe src="newPage.html"></iframe>

<style>
.bold { font-weight: bold }
iframe {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

**newPage.html**

```
<p class="bold">Iframe page bold</p>
```

If you access the main page in your browser you will see 2 paragraphs:

1. Main page bold (will be bold)
2. Iframe page bold (will not be bold)

---

If you don't want to make a new page, you can also create an iframe with JavaScript, and fill it with HTML, like so:

```
<script>
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = '<p class="bold">Iframe page bold</p>';
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

createShadowRoot() has been deprecated. Click here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot

Answer (score 1):

Use iframe with srcdoc. This is how HTML messages work in my chat.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
// iframe.sandbox().add(...) // if you need some security
iframe.srcdoc = "<html><head><style>body {margin: 0;}</style></head><body>" + <your code> + "</body></html>";
```

and then add it to element

```
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

(replace body with your element)

If you need to set another styles on iframe, just link it with `<link rel="stylesheet">`.
Also, don't forget to set `border: none;` in your CSS